# Debugging into library code from VSCode Jupyter

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, vscode-debugger, vscode-remote

I'm using VS Code + Jupyter Notebooks to develop ML-based things in python.
I can successfully place breakpoints inside the notebook cells, but weirdly enough, if I try to step into a function that isn't defined there, it steps over it.

Example:
[image]

In this cell I am debugging a function called run() which calls model.generate(...), which in turns calls a callback function filter_allowed_tokens defined in a different cell. In this breakpoint, I am inside filter_allowed_tokens(), and according to the call stack (bottom left of screenshot), the frame below is run(), even though, clearly, there should be a generate() frame in the middle.

This is consistent with the fact that I am unable to step into it.
This call stack is very weird and I have a hard time explaining it to myself. Is there a setting that causes "full call stacks", and hopefully I will be able to step into the library code that is called from the notebook's cells?

If it has any effect, I am running on windows using WSL.

If I take all of my notebook's code and paste it into a normal python file, the step into will work as expected. However, I would like to do it using jupyter as it allows me to keep the ML models in memory between runs...

Comment: Yes, it does! In this case the code was my code, but outside the .ipynb notebook, but I guess the solution works either way

Comment: then confirm to close it as a duplicate.